# elim clicked <label> <div> <checkbox>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Below is a jsfiddle link that has got the code in it that needs modifying.

http://jsfiddle.net/N44Ah/

This is HTML code within the above jsfiddle link

```
<label for="cb">
    <div id="clickablediv">
        <input name="cb" id="cb" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</label>
<label for="cb">
    <div id="clickablediv">
        <input name="cb" id="cb" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</label>
```

This is the javascript within the above jsfiddle link

```
$('#clickablediv').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('#cb').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 250);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

and this is the basic CSS

```
#clickablediv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Basically I can't changed the div id, class or details as they are created from php after a database query what pulls an array and then fills each div with the required info for that div and then populates the next div until all information has been displayed in different divs.

I understand it is the javascript that needs to be modified here but I am just unsure on how to do it as I am not any good at javascript.

I need the effect to be so what ever div you click is the div that is effected because at the minute what ever div you click it only effects the top div.

once again I can't changed the div's id, class or details.

This maybe un-relevant but I did have the same sort of issue when I was creating buttons and hidden divs in the same way except when clicking the buttons it needed to display the correct div tied to it however in the above question I need to do a dim effect as what you can see in the js above.

below is the jsfiddle link to the code about the buttons and hidden divs using a (elim) function in javascript I am not sure if the same sort of elim method needs to be adopted for my new problem I am having.

http://jsfiddle.net/gpDFc/

I have tried to mess around with the both javascripts but as I am no good I didn't managed to make a working script.

Thank you for your time in reading this and I look forward to yuor help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct Values required in DOM

```
See here, modified fiddle: 

http://jsfiddle.net/N44Ah/1/
```

Comment: that works but it also changes information. The check box is inside the div so that also gets duplicated and is the same probablem as in changing the divs id, class or any details.

Comment: well, that's against the design practices and recommendation. You shouldn't have two elements with same IDs, otherwise the first found one gets manipulated ultimately.

Comment: they are dupliacted because of php. I didn't include my original code as it is very long and is not needed. If you click the 2nd jsfiddle link you will see that it is possible to use the elim function.

Comment: I changed your code around a little and I have managed to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

ID of an element must be unique.

The ID selector will return the first element with the said id, so your code will attach the click handler only to the first div with id `clickablediv` not to the second

Since you have repeated at least twice that the id cannot be changed, use an attribute selector to select the div's with the said id.

```
$('div[id="clickablediv"]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('[name="cb"]').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 250);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 250);
    }
});
```

Comment: did you click the 2nd jsfiddle link? that displays the fact that you do not need to have different id's for the divs and can use a elim function

Comment: @Luke then the event handler are not registered using selectors, it is an inline handler... the problem is `$('#clickablediv')` returns only 1 element

Comment: Thank you for your answer tho but it isn't quite what i am looking for

Comment: @Luke what is the changes you are looking for

Comment: The same effect as it has except it needs to effect the div that is clicked. I am referring to the 1st jsfiddle link I shared

Comment: @Luke the most difficult part here is that you have an invalid html

Comment: invalid html? Please explain

Comment: that is because it is processed using php `$mail .= 'DIVS and CONTENT'; and then `echo $mail` making the div id a changeable php variable (e.g database id for actual data) doesn't work as js only picks up the last id and has no effect. Can the elim function not be worked within this js script like the second jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of id like below. For entire page you can use single id. If you have multiple id with same name, first id only will be affected.

```
<label for="cb">
    <div class="clickablediv">
        <input name="cb" id="cb" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</label>
<label for="cb">
    <div class="clickablediv">
        <input name="cb" id="cb" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</label>

$('.clickablediv').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('#cb').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.5
        }, 250);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 250);
    }
});

.clickablediv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: That just does the same effect. I can't make the class or id unique as they are duplicated using php